# JsFiddle: Any way to use a separate x.js to test isJsFileLoaded()

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

[2021.10.20 Edited to add sample code about the question.]
First time user of JsFiddle.  Just discovered :)

I have an html plus js page, which tests ok from a server.

To load the file, html has

```
<script src='x.js'></script>
```

I have a function

```
function isLoaded() { 
 return Boolean(document.querySelector('script[src=\"x.js\"]')); }
```

and it works.

I would like to know if I can test the above from the free version ofJsFiddle?  If so, how do I specify (add) the x.js file to the JsFiddle ide?

Thank you!

Comment: what exactly do you want? You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this I learned about the following way to get around my problem.

Serve x.js from a server example.com and add to the HTML section

```
<script src='https://example.com/x.js'> </script>
```

I still do not know if jsFiddle has the functionality to accept by upload a file, and serve it the above way internally, without having to use an external server.  If not, hopefully this would be available in a future version of jsFiddle.

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of write as answer.

Comment: Beller, Thanks. I am learning  But If i edit my original question as an answer only, that wont be a question any more. No?